# Good java webmail applications

Tags: java, imap, webmail

Are there good java webmail applications, that can be used to connect to standalone imap servers?

Something like roundcube but that can be deployed in an application server.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder whether this question belongs on serverfault.com.  Are you asking from a developer perspective or an administrator perspective?

Comment: Administrator perspective. I didn't new about serverfault.com

Comment: Even though this question is "off-topic" for SO, it has its significance for developers dealing with mail servers. I don't always like to type my mails directly into `nc` or such while developing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Updated 2019 for current state of referenced projects)*

Some open source solutions can still be found [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/web-mail):

[JWebMail](http://jwebmail.sourceforge.net/) (last release 1.0.1rc1, 2008-10-31, [files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jwebmail/files/jwebmail/))

[jwma (Java Webmail)](http://jwma.sourceforge.net/) (last release 2.6.4, 2018-11-09, [files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jwma/files/))

[Gatormail](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gatormail/) (last release 1.0.11, 2004-05-03, [files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gatormail/files/))

[Claros inTouch](http://www.claros.org/) (last release 2.1, 2007-06-10, downloads are gone but still on [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20100924144948/http://claros.org/products/claros-intouch-2.1.zip))

[yawebmail](http://yawebmail.sourceforge.net/) (last release 1.2.5, 2008-12-15, [files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/yawebmail/files/yawebmail/))

Comment: I read that other question, but JavaMail, from the documentation, looks like a library and not an application. Couldn't find a download for gatormail. JWebMail (2008), yawebmail (2008), jwma, from the available screenshots looks ugly. Claros I need to check...

Comment: That's true about JavaMail; the application server bit distracted me, what can I say? :P Looks like GatorMail is a no go. http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~pf1/gatormailproposal.html And I thought Claros looked pretty well-marketed, so maybe it's a decent product, and free.

Comment: This columba: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columba_(e-mail_client) ? Looks like a fat client to me. And the last update was in 2007....