# feedback about any webmail clients in java suggested in different threads

Tags: jakarta-ee, webmail

My need is to have some webmail client to be integrated with my java application.
So naturally I will prefer some java client.

There are good alternatives like roundCube,squirrelmail etc but most of them are in PHP.

I have seen this thread and few others
[Good java webmail applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036467/good-java-webmail-applications)

but no one seems to have commented about 
JWebmail or other alternatives.

How good is this Jwebmail. Anyone worked on it? Or any other java alternative? I don't see any answers saying something out of this is working good.

JWebMail

WebMail

Claros inTouch

yawebmail

zkmail

lastly
I wonder why there are plenty of good php alternatives and not java?